# Django-tenant-schemas and GeoDjango together

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

I want to use [django-tenant-schemas](http://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and [GeoDjango (PostGIS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) in my Django project. I have a single default database. But both django-tenant-schemas and GeoDjango want me to set a custom Engine for the Database in the settings.

django-tenant-schemas want it to be set to `tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend` 
while GeoDjango wants it to be set to `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis`.

Is there any workaround to this issue?

*Edit:* I want to use GeoDjango for a single model only and I am using a single Postgres database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I solved this is by changing ORIGINAL_BACKEND in tenant_schame.postgresql_backend.base. I changed it to

```
ORIGINAL_BACKEND = getattr(settings, 'ORIGINAL_BACKEND', 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis')
```

from

```
ORIGINAL_BACKEND = getattr(settings, 'ORIGINAL_BACKEND', 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2')
```